# Real-time, dynamic generating image sharing on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, image, share

I'm trying to create simple facebook game. There is really required to do as much as possible on client-side. I generate dynamic .jpg to share game results on facebook wall using Feed method of FB.ui api. I've tried to use this code as image generator:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$pictureUrl = $_REQUEST['pic'];
$firstPlayerResult = $_REQUEST['fpr'];
$firstPlayerName = $_REQUEST['fpn'];
$secondPlayerResult = $_REQUEST['spr'];
$secondPlayerName = $_REQUEST['spn'];

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($pictureUrl);


$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
$verdanaBold = './verdanab.ttf';
$verdana = './verdana.ttf';

imagefttext($im, 16, 0, 12, 33, $white, $verdanaBold, $firstPlayerResult);
imagefttext($im, 12, 0, 12, 50, $white, $verdana, $firstPlayerName);

$dimensions = imagettfbbox(12, 0, $verdana, $secondPlayerName);
$textWidth = abs($dimensions[4] - $dimensions[0]);
$x = 693 - $textWidth;

imagefttext($im, 16, 0, 603, 33, $white, $verdanaBold, $secondPlayerResult);
imagefttext($im, 12, 0, $x, 50, $white, $verdana, $secondPlayerName);

imagejpeg($im);
?>
```

But there is a problem. Script works fine when is opening in a browser - its display correct .jpg screen, but when I'm trying to past the URL link (with GET request) to js script into 'picture' field of Feed method from FB.ui, its return internal error (500). Similiar behaviour appears when I'm trying directly past link on my facebook wall (facebook don't parse image and displays only URL). How can I fix it and display correctly image as facebook feed?

Comment: Have you tried checking your image URL in the [Graph API debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked URL in debbuger. Response is: "Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

Comment: Your script is sending invalid information and Facebook won't parse it. Take a deeper look at the headers with the W3C validator and the developer tools in Chrome/Safari/Firebug.

Comment: As a further thought, how are you trying to share this image? If you're sharing it as a URL instead of as an image, you need to have an HTML page with the proper open graph tags on this and your image embedded in an `og:image` tag.

Comment: I want to share this image as picture field in a feed method from FB.ui,  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ in an example on a facebook developers site picture field is an URL to jpg file. W3C Validator detect content type as image/jpeg.

Comment: Can you share an example URL?

Comment: http://podludek.uphero.com/shareImageGenerator.php?pic=http://podludek.uphero.com/resources/img/FB_share/FB-post_screen2_status9.jpg&fpr=000002&fpn=DOMINIKA&spr=000003&spn=JANO

Comment: I can't see what the problem is with this. I'm doing something similar to fetch a page's picture and feed it back into an `og:image tag`. My response time is longer than yours. I don't see a difference in the headers that you return vs. me. I do have only one GET variable in my implementation.

Comment: There is one thing we didn't consider. Domain uphero is marked by facebook as source of spam. I suppose this is the reason of this problem, I will check this as soon as I will find a free hosting with the GD library included.

Comment: As I've supposed changing domain helped. Now it works fine when I'm trying to sharing page through directly passing an url into facebook wall, but it still doesn't work as a picture field of feed method.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, because it's generated in the Front-end part and isn't saved as a proper image file. So the url isn't a permalink that it should be for you to be able to post something to FB